# Using lapply (or any alternative) with data.table to generate several columns at once

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with several variables (columns) and their standard errors.  I'd like to calculate several things such as the weighted mean, the mean of the standard error, p-values...

Toy example:

```
myDT <- data.table(ID=1:8, AA=21:28, BB=31:38, CC=41:48, stdAA=(11:18)/10, 
    stdBB=(11:18)/10, stdCC=(11:18)/10)
mycol <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")   # Select these ones.


   ID AA BB CC stdAA stdBB stdCC
1:  1 21 31 41   1.1   1.1   1.1
2:  2 22 32 42   1.2   1.2   1.2
3:  3 23 33 43   1.3   1.3   1.3
4:  4 24 34 44   1.4   1.4   1.4
5:  5 25 35 45   1.5   1.5   1.5
6:  6 26 36 46   1.6   1.6   1.6
7:  7 27 37 47   1.7   1.7   1.7
8:  8 28 38 48   1.8   1.8   1.8

OUTPUT1 <- myDT[,.(Variables=mycol,Estimate=lapply(mycol, 
   function (x) weighted.mean(get(x), 1/(get(paste0("std",x)))^2 ) ),
   Std.Error=lapply(mycol, function (x) mean(get(paste0("std",x)))))]  
OUTPUT1[,tvalue := as.numeric(Estimate)/as.numeric(Std.Error) ][,pvalue := 2*pt(-abs(tvalue),df=7)]


   Variables Estimate    Std.Error  tvalue       pvalue
        AA    23.76617      1.45   16.39046   7.671357e-07
        BB    33.76617      1.45   23.28702   6.833554e-08
        CC    43.76617      1.45   30.18357   1.129896e-08
```

I've calculated the two last colums later because they need a previously calculated value, but there is a problem, it produces an error *"non-numeric argument to binary operator",* that's why I'm using "as.numeric" .
I guess the problem is that the generated data.table contains lists instead of vectors.
I would like to get it with a simpler syntax, inserting everything inside the same lapply.

How can I do it?

The following code doesn't produce the expected output because it inserts a vector on each element of the second column, they I can't further work with it.

```
OUTPUT2 <- myDT[,.(mycol,lapply(mycol, function (x) 
  c(weighted.mean(get(x),1/(get(paste0("std",x)))^2 ),
   mean(get(paste0("std",x))) )))]
```

Maybe I need to add some kind of rbindlist but I haven't be able to do it properly.

My next try works though it's not shorter. (And I haven't event added columnames because they get removed, I need to add them later)

```
OUTPUT3 <- data.table(mycol,t(myDT[,c(lapply(mycol,
        function (x) .(weighted.mean(get(x),1/(get(paste0("std",x)))^2 ), 
           mean(get(paste0("std",x))))))]))
OUTPUT3[,tvalue := as.numeric(V1)/as.numeric(V2)][,pvalue := 2*pt(-abs(tvalue),df=7)]
```

It would be great to have all calculations inside a single lapply.

Answer (score 2):

And if melt it first? It simplifies the problem a lot:

```
melt(
  melt(myDT, 1:4, 5:7, 'Variable', 'StdError'), 
  c(1, 6),
  c('AA', 'BB', 'CC'),
  'Variable',
  'Estimate'
    )[, .(Variable, Estimate, StdError)
    ][
      , .(Estimate = weighted.mean(Estimate, 1 / StdError^2),
          StdError = mean(StdError)),
        .(Variable)
    ][
      , `:=`(tvalue    =  Estimate / StdError,
             pvalue    = 2 * pt(-abs(Estimate / StdError), df = 7)),
        .(Variable)
    ]

   Variable Estimate StdError   tvalue       pvalue
1:       AA 23.76617     1.45 16.39046 7.671357e-07
2:       BB 33.76617     1.45 23.28702 6.833554e-08
3:       CC 43.76617     1.45 30.18357 1.129896e-08
```

Comment: Nice.  You don't need this line [, .(Variable, Estimate, StdError)
    ]

Answer (score 1):

Someone may come up with something more elegant. But if the goal is to calculate everything inside a single `lapply`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

myDT <- data.table(ID=1:8, AA=21:28, BB=31:38, CC=41:48, stdAA=(11:18)/10, 
                   stdBB=(11:18)/10, stdCC=(11:18)/10)

mycol <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")   # Select these ones.

newCols <- c("Estimate", "Std.Error", "tvalue", "pvalue")

myDT[, .(lapply(mycol, function(x){
  estimate <- weighted.mean(get(x), 1/(get(paste0("std",x)))^2 )
  std.error <- mean(get(paste0("std",x)))
  tvalue <- estimate/std.error
  pvalue <- 2*pt(-abs(tvalue),df=7)
  out <- list(estimate, std.error, tvalue, pvalue)
  return(out)
}))] %>% rbindlist %>% 
  t(.) %>% 
  as.data.table(.) %>% 
  setnames(., names(.), newCols) %>% .[] # visualize table
```

Comment: In fact I'm looking for something elegant and short. Preferably not using other libraries such as magrittr or dplyr.

Comment: You don't need `magrittr` or `dplyr` in the code above. Just replace the pipes with the repeated assignment of `myDT`. I added pipes for readability.